how to dump rows from mysqldump to reimport into different table
I need to dump data from one table in my MySQL 8 database and reimport into a different table which already exists and has it's schema. The schema is identical between the two such as columns, how can I achieve this, i just need the row imsert statements from mysqldump without locking and create info
My export:
mysqldump -u root -p --no-create-info icicle_db users > users_existing.sql

I've tried to import
mysqldump -u root -p --no-create-info icicle_db users_new < users_existing.sql

But users_existing.sql contains references to the old table, i just need insert data not other schema. I'm trying it on a small table before trying a table with millions of rows. What am i missing?

I want to export from one table, but have the export reference a new table for importing


But users_existing.sql contains references to the old table, i just
need insert data not other schema. I'm trying it on a small table
before trying a table with millions of rows. What am I missing?

You need to replace the table name in users_existing.sql file.
This can be done using sed command.
sudo sed -i 's/INSERT INTO `users`/INSERT INTO `users_new`/g' users_existing.sql

Then proceed with the restore
mysql -u root -p icicle_db < users_existing.sql


There's no need for sudo. mysqldump creates the file with the current user as owner, not root.

Thanks! This solves it, though takes a while to insert 6 million

Here's the solution I would use: import the table to a new schema, then rename the table.
Demo: I have a table in my test schema named mytable. I dump this table.
$ mysqldump test mytable > mytable.sql

The dump file will restore the table by its original name, but in whatever the current schema is when you run the restore.
So I create a new, empty schema.
$ mysqladmin create test2

And restore the dump to that schema.
$ mysql test2 < mytable.sql

The table is now imported, using its original name, but it has not conflicted with the original table in test, because the new table is in a different schema. In the same way that you can have two files of the same name on your computer, if they are in different folders.
mysql> use test2
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_test2 |
+-----------------+
| mytable         |
+-----------------+

Then rename that restored table, to move it into the original schema test, but with a new name. Renaming a table is a quick operation, regardless of the size of the data in the table.
mysql> rename table test2.mytable to test.mytable_new;

Check the tables present in the test schema to make sure the new table is there.
mysql> use test
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| mytable        |
| mytable_new    |
+----------------+


Since it has more steps than sed it is not easier, but it is safer and faster solution. I didnt consider rename table. +1

OK, I've edited the first line. "Easier" is subjective. :-)

Why not copying the data without dump?
# drop new table if exists
drop table if exists users_new;

# create new table as clone
create table users_new like users;

# copy data
insert into users_new select * from users;


This seems to have been asked here:
How can I import a mysql dump?
Quick answer:
mysql -uroot -p database_name < backup.sql



Doesn't solve what I'm asking
